# Why float box out of parent box?

Tags: html, css

Sometimes, float box out of parent box, I have to add "width:100%;overflow:hidden" to parent to stop this.

So, why float box can out of parent? Is this a standard behavior?

```
<div style=" border:1px solid #F00">
  <div style="float:left">float</div>
</div>
```

Comment: posting the a small snippet which illustrates your problem succinctly would help us to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pitfall which I think everyone has fallen into, probably on more than one occasion.

Here are some good resources for understanding how CSS floats work:

- http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ *See the section called "The Great Collapse"*
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/
- http://phrogz.net/css/understandingfloats.html

Answer (score 3):

Floating elements are removed from the normal document flow.  In order to make their parent wrap around them, you need to put something after the floater with the `clear:` property set.

```
<div style=" border:1px solid #F00">
  <div style="float:left">float</div>
  <br style="clear:both;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another div after the floated div which contains the style rule clear: both. A div containing a single floated child div will always collapse and have it's child float out.